# How to test components using react-query with msw and react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query, msw

I have a page with a dropdown component being loaded into it. This component calls a customhook that uses react query to get data to show in the dropdown.
On initial load this component is in a **loading** state and renders a loading icon.
When react-query finishes the call successfully the component renders the list of data into the dropdown.

```
const SelectItem = ({ handleSelectChange, selectedItem }) => {
  
  const { data, status } = useGetData(url, 'myQueryKey');

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <RenderSkeleton />;
  }

  if (status === 'error') {
    return 'An Error has occured';
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        options={data}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.name}`}
        value={selectedItem}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          handleSelectChange(newValue);
        }}
        data-testid="select-data"
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params}" />}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

How do I test this correctly?
my test only renders the Skeleton component even after implementing msw to mock the response data. So I assume it basically only awaits the "isLoading" state.

```
it('should load A Selectbox data', async () => {
  render(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <SelectItem />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
  expect(await screen.getByTestId('select-data')).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Please note I also implemented msw mock server and handlers to mock the data it should return.
BTW Before using react query It worked like a charm, so I guess I am overseeing something.

Thank you!

Comment: Your mocked data is returning a promise with some timeout? Did you try using `findByText` (will wait for the DOM element) from react-testing-library like; `expect(await screen.findByText('select-data')).toBeInTheDocument();`

Comment: Thank you, this actually solved it! Thought it was some stupid mistake!!

Comment: Nice! Just posted the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `findByText` (will wait for the DOM element, returning a `Promise`)

```
expect(await screen.findByText('select-data')).toBeInTheDocument();
```